# Generic extending class AND implements interface

Tags: java, generics, interface, enums

This might sound like an odd question but how can on define a generic which has to extend a class AND to implement an interface? Im currently having a generic function with the following prototype:

```
public static <E extends Enum<E>> List<E> buildEnumList(Class<E> enumClass)
```

This works just as intented. My problem now is that I want to further restrict the passable classes to those which are enums and implement a specific interface `Readable` (not that in java.lang). Since a generic uses the same keyword `extends` to indicate that it should implement an interface, I dont see any way to get the following pseudo behaviour:

```
public static <E extends Enum<E> implements Readable> List<E> buildLexicographicalEnumList(Class<E> enumClass)
```

Answer (score 26, accepted):

You can use `&` to indicate that `E` must also implement an interface:

```
public static <E extends Enum<E> & Readable> List<E> buildLexicographicalEnumList(Class<E> enumClass) {
```

Comment: A comma can also be used to separate them.

Comment: @corsiKa I thought so too but can't find it [in the JLS](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-4.html#jls-4.4). Although it does to compile.

Comment: Now I'm concerned they actually do two different things... :-(

Comment: It defines a second/nth type parameter.

Comment: @BenSchulz Indeed; A comma was my first try but it instead defined a second type parameter. This however works just fine

Comment: @corsiKa: Be carefull here: Comma does a different thing. The & is the correct way to specify what OP needs.